# Add Dimension Attributes Using MDX script

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, cube

Hello I want to know if is possible to modify a cube dimension in order to Add a New attribute through a MDX script. I can do it using the MS BIDS, but I need to add this attribute for a single customer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MDX Script is for calculations performed in the cube and is not for cube dimensions. On the other hand, you can use XMLA script to create objects: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187152.aspx.